# How can I get a single character from a string?

Tags: strings

I'm trying to make a command (macro? not sure about terminology) that takes in as input a string `s`, a number `n`, and a character `c`, and returns true if the `n`th character of `s` is `c`, and false otherwise (preferably by using as few external packages as possible, since I'm trying to learn).

Comment: TeX doesn't have strings in the sense of other languages; how do you want to handle for example `{abc}d`?

Comment: also what's the 3rd character in  `é£α` (this is 6 character tokens)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your strings only consist of printable ASCII character that are not special for TeX (braces, in particular), you can do it with no package at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkcharacterTF}{mmmmm}
 {% #1 = string of characters
  % #2 = integer
  % #3 = character
  % #4 = true text
  % #5 = false text
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 > \str_count:n { #1 } }
   {% the integer exceeds the string length
    #5
   }
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { #3 } { \str_item:nn { #1 } { #2 } } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\checkcharacterTF{abcde}{3}{c}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\checkcharacterTF{abcde}{3}{x}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\checkcharacterTF{abcde}{6}{c}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What are `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and `{mmmmm}` doing here?  Or do those have to do with this being TeX and not LaTeX (which I suppose is really what I should have asked about).

Also, unrelated, but how many times would I have to run this for it to significantly affect compilation time?  Would running this thousands or tens of thousands of times cause a problem?